# Rooted, but su hangs

Tags: htc-droid-incredible, root-access

I've had my phone rooted and flashed/reset/reflashed it several times in the last couple years. However, I recently reflashed to the stock image found [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2141642).

When I try to use SU apps, it prompts to allow, I say yes, it seems to proceed as I'm used to, but nothing happens.

So I open up trusty terminal and get a $. I type `su`, prompt/approve, but it just hangs. I never get a #. No error, no permission denied, nothing. I'm assuming this is the underlying cause of why SU doesn't seem to work for anything.

I've checked and confirmed that setuid is set:

`-rwsr-sr-x root root ..... su`

So I'm kind of at a loss here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should re-root, the presence and accessibility of `su` doesn't really mean anything.

Comment: Try a different SU app like [SuperSU](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.supersu&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImV1LmNoYWluZmlyZS5zdXBlcnN1Il0.), and also make sure that you have [busybox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox&hl=en) installed in `/system/bin/sh`

Answer (score 1):

Matthew was right. Though since most of the steps had been already done from original rooting, I simply redownloaded the Superuser.zip and installed from recovery.

Fixed the problem.

Thanks.